# python-write to file (ignore non-ascii chars)

Tags: python, file, utf-8

I am on Linux and a want to write string (in utf-8) to txt file. I tried many ways, but I always got an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position in position 36: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there any way, how to write to file only ascii characters? And ignore non-ascii characters.
My code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8-*-

import os
import sys


def __init__(self, dirname, speaker, file, exportFile):

  text_file = open(exportFile, "a")

  text_file.write(speaker.encode("utf-8"))
  text_file.write(file.encode("utf-8"))

  text_file.close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Strip _non-ascii_ characters before writing?

Comment: Did you try `speaker.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')`? However I believe you are doing wrong something else, because you *shouldn't* have that error in the first place. Could you show us what are `speaker` and `file`? Also, if you want to write binary data to a file you should open the file in binary mode: `open(export_file, 'ab')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`codecs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html?highlight=codecs#codecs) module.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8-*-

import codecs


def __init__(self, dirname, speaker, file, exportFile):

  with codecs.open(exportFile, "a", 'utf-8') as text_file:
      text_file.write(speaker.encode("utf-8"))
      text_file.write(file.encode("utf-8"))
```

Also, beware that your `file` variable has a name which collides with the builtin [`file`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=file#file) function.

Finally, I would suggest you have a look at http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html to better understand what is unicode, and one of these pages (depending on your python version) to understand how to use it in Python:

- http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode
- http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: I tried many ways (also codecs), but I always got the same error. So, I want to ignore non-ascii characters and write to file only ascii. (I don´t have variable with name "file" in my program, this is only example).

Comment: What seems to happen is that your variable is of type ``str``. So when you do ``str.encode('utf-8')``, python automagically casts your ``str`` to ``unicode``, by encoding it with the system default encoding (ascii in python2). I guess it's this implicit conversion that fails, given the mention of 'ascii' in your error message. Are you sure *all* your variables are of type ``unicode``?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `codecs` module:

```
import codecs
text_file = codecs.open(exportFile,mode='a',encoding='utf-8')
text_file.write(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could decode your input string before writing it;

```
text = speaker.decode("utf8")
with open(exportFile, "a") as text_file:
    text_file.write(text.encode("utf-8"))
    text_file.write(file.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: str has no attribute decode!

Comment: @greendino you're using python 3. Back in 2014 I was mostly using python 2 which could decode a string.